# Distance error with pgr_withPointsCost

Tags: postgis, pgrouting

Using pgrouting 3.1, I'm getting a error when doing a many to many calculation.

I've reduced it to a one to many to try and find out what I'm doing wrong.

So with a starting point (green) [33] and end points (pink) [left to right 29, 30 ,31]
[image]
I get distances (m) of:

| "start_vid" | "start_geom" | "end_vid" | "end_geom" | "distance" |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 33 | "POINT(486622.14439999964 6951376.4575)" | 31 | "POINT(486853.7922216329 6951407.584744054)" | 4.217604918633195 |
| 33 | "POINT(486622.14439999964 6951376.4575)" | 30 | "POINT(486787.0424740781 6951458.998532209)" | 4.217544113633195 |
| 33 | "POINT(486622.14439999964 6951376.4575)" | 29 | "POINT(486785.6968050292 6951458.780481533)" | 4.217664498633198 |

now I would have expected distances to be around the ~300m mark and for 31 to be a lot different then 29,30

can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

This is the Data I'm testing with:
test_network:

```sql
CREATE SEQUENCE public.test_network_id_seq
    INCREMENT 1
    START 1
    MINVALUE 1
    MAXVALUE 2147483647
    CACHE 1;
 
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.test_network
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('test_network_id_seq'::regclass),
    geom geometry(LineString,28356),
    cost double precision,
    source integer,
    target integer,
    CONSTRAINT test_network_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
 
INSERT INTO public.test_network (id, geom, cost, source, target)
    VALUES
        (1, '0102000020C46E00000200000000E78CE8AFB81D4139D6C5652D845A4130ED0DFEAEB81D41D044D8742D845A41', 0.328, 1, 2),
        (7, '0102000020C46E00000200000010462535E9B91D41D93D793C1E845A4160AA6094F1B91D419A9999791E845A41', 2.3, 3, 4),
        (39, '0102000020C46E000008000000404ED15126B41D41992A18A990845A41002B871638B41D411DC9E5B790845A412075025A4DB41D417958A8C990845A41F0B9DACA65B41D414F1E16DE90845A4190DB68C0B4B41D419A99995990845A41604BC847CAB41D41D7A3703590845A4140477239D6B41D41CE19510A90845A4160F7E461EAB41D418104C5BF8F845A41', 49.384, 5, 6),
        (2, '0102000020C46E00000600000000000000B0B91D41CD3B4E0D50845A41D0D556ECDCB91D41EC51B8124F845A4160666666F9B91D41789CA29B50845A41F0FDD4F802BA1D41EC2FBB1F51845A412075025A05BA1D415BB1BFF053845A41E04F8D5706BA1D41ED0DBE1C55845A41', 40.432, 7, 8),
        (3, '0102000020C46E00000A000000A045B63343B31D4104560E0589845A41007F6A7C44B31D41431CEBEA87845A41802F4C264CB31D41F2B0507F81845A4140355E3A4CB31D41A2B4376481845A4180AEB6A250B31D417958A8A97D845A4160764F5E54B31D41B9FC878C7C845A410034113658B31D41744694667B845A41D0CCCCCC59B31D411B9E5EED7A845A41F02FBB276BB31D417DAEB6BE75845A41C05296E170B31D416C787A0D75845A41', 81.018, 9, 10),
        (4, '0102000020C46E000008000000C05296E170B31D416C787A0D75845A41F097DD9378B31D4114AE471D74845A41907EFB7A91B31D418716D91671845A41C0B12EAEA6B31D4154E3A5836E845A41B0AF03A7ACB31D413D0AD71B6E845A41506B9A77B4B31D416EA301946D845A417091ED7CB6B31D414260E5706D845A41B09DEFA7C1B31D415D6DC5AE6C845A41', 39.367, 10, 11),
        (5, '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', 147.711, 12, 13),
        (6, '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', 112.1, 2, 14),
        (8, '0102000020C46E000003000000A0C64BB7ABB61D41C3D32B056D845A4110E9B7EFAAB61D41F7065FB86B845A4130DD24C6AAB61D41D0D556746B845A41', 6.268, 15, 16),
        (9, '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', 100.737, 17, 7),
        (10, '0102000020C46E000002000000002B871637C01D413D2CD4FA20845A4100D578E94DC01D41006F816020845A41', 6.164, 18, 19),
        (11, '0102000020C46E000006000000D0A145B6CDC11D41B5A679F71A845A4190ED7CFFD1C11D417C6132F11B845A417024977FF4C11D418CDB689423845A41F0B9DACAFAC11D41992A18F924845A4190976E9212C21D412E90A0402A845A41D0A370BD12C21D41E0BE0E502A845A41', 63.765, 20, 21),
        (12, '0102000020C46E00000200000050499D4010BE1D411AC05BF054845A414079586822BE1D41A857CAA654845A41', 4.682, 22, 23),
        (13, '0102000020C46E000007000000E0E995F250B51D41F7E4615577845A41F0C9C3C230B51D414260E5B078845A4180855A932DB51D415A643BD378845A416039B44829B51D4176E09C0179845A41401CEB2227B51D4138F8C21879845A4110B5A6B927B51D411DC9E5A779845A4190B0E1A928B51D413108AC787A845A41', 18.123, 24, 25),
        (14, '0102000020C46E00000800000090B0E1A904B51D413B70CE109A845A41D0F753E30EB51D41E86A2B2A9E845A41E0F97EEA0DB51D41E10B93BD9E845A41606DC57E0CB51D41A323B9949F845A41F02FBB270BB51D41E0BE0E60A0845A41D0DEE0CB0AB51D4187A75796A0845A4150499DC0F3B41D417DD0B399A2845A4170567D6EF3B41D4155302AA1A2845A41', 36.405, 26, 12),
        (15, '0102000020C46E0000020000001093A90209B61D4130BB27E788845A41C01E852BDBB51D41764F1E9E84845A41', 20.625, 27, 28),
        (16, '0102000020C46E0000040000008058A8B529B71D4186C9548D3D845A4100000000F6B61D41C3F5288442845A41E04F8D57F1B61D41006F814043845A41B04082E2EDB61D41A69BC4CC43845A41', 29.221, 29, 30),
        (17, '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', 129.57, 31, 30),
        (18, '0102000020C46E000006000000C0D32BE55DBB1D414260E57016845A41400AD72359BB1D41143FC62017845A4130431C2B46BB1D415DFE43DE19845A41A09BC4A032BB1D41143FC6B01C845A41F053E3652ABB1D416F8104E11D845A410066F76421BB1D411B0DE02D1F845A41', 38.086, 32, 33),
        (19, '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', 125.079, 34, 35),
        (20, '0102000020C46E000007000000607FD97D97BB1D418D28ED596B845A41D019511A84BB1D41F6285CE76A845A4130189514D9BA1D4196438BF466845A41E01DA728D2BA1D41789CA2CB66845A41001973179CBA1D41984C158C65845A41204A7B4380BA1D4109F9A0E764845A41A0559F6B73BA1D417E8CB99B64845A41', 77.84, 36, 17),
        (21, '0102000020C46E00000B000000506210581BC21D41F2D24D722D845A41B08251891BC21D41615452C32E845A41709CA2A31BC21D41DB8AFD792F845A41402CD41A1CC21D4179E926A932845A41003411361CC21D414CA60A6633845A4110363C3D1CC21D41FB3A709A33845A4100F775E009C21D4114D044A038845A41D000DE02E8C11D412041F14F3D845A4140355E3AE2C11D41006F81D03D845A4120C9E5BFC9C11D412E90A0F03F845A4190DB6880BEC11D41AB3E57EB40845A41', 83.578, 37, 38),
        (22, '0102000020C46E000003000000009A089B31C11D41910F7A3E48845A41A0DFBECE31C11D41A8C64B4748845A4100CE19D130C11D410A68221849845A41', 3.419, 39, 40),
        (23, '0102000020C46E00000D000000F016481032B51D4105A392B261845A41F051B85E12B51D41F7065FB861845A418095438BEAB41D410D71ACBF61845A41A0ABAD98B4B41D41547424C362845A4100CE19D19CB41D412506813563845A4190A9829199B41D4104560E4563845A41F0D24DE26DB41D417AA52C1764845A41002B871617B41D41DAACFA7C67845A4140696F7008B41D41F31FD20F68845A41D09AE69DFFB31D413789416868845A41A033A234CFB31D41F9A067BF6B845A41C096908FCAB31D41903177116C845A41B09DEFA7C1B31D415D6DC5AE6C845A41', 106.026, 41, 11),
        (24, '0102000020C46E000007000000E068006FC9B51D41B537F84662845A4190E4F2DFB8B51D4150FC182B62845A4190A0F8B1ADB51D41F7065F1862845A41B0D100DE86B51D419BE61DD761845A4110FBCBEE6AB51D410A6822A861845A41D0E76AEB62B51D419A9999A961845A41F016481032B51D4105A392B261845A41', 37.974, 42, 41),
        (25, '0102000020C46E00000C000000C01E852BDBB51D41764F1E9E84845A41D078E966D1B51D418E06F0B683845A4170E09CD1C7B51D41BD5296D182845A410044FA2DBEB51D41FCA9F1EA81845A4130FF21FDB8B51D41ABCFD56E81845A41A080268293B51D41ECC039EF7D845A41D088D29E92B51D41992A18B97D845A4100F775E08FB51D41E5F21F127D845A4120EBE2F67EB51D417FFB3A0C79845A4190A982917DB51D41A8C64BB778845A4130431C2B7CB51D419F3C2CAC78845A41E0E995F250B51D41F7E4615577845A41', 66.214, 28, 24),
        (26, '0102000020C46E000009000000B003E70C10B41D4140A4DF9290845A41303A924BFDB31D416154528390845A4130189514E3B31D412F6EA36D90845A41806ABC74C7B31D413C4ED10D90845A418051495DB2B31D41A323B9C48F845A4100D578E984B31D41C8073D278F845A410032E62E83B31D41A3923A218F845A414094F68679B31D412063EEF28E845A4140014D442EB31D41DB8AFD898D845A41', 57.95, 43, 44),
        (27, '0102000020C46E000002000000806132551AB71D415DFE43BE7B845A4110E9B7EFFAB61D411973D7427D845A41', 9.923, 45, 46),
        (28, '0102000020C46E000005000000809ECDAA23B71D41F241CF827C845A414094F68624B71D4111363C957C845A4130431C2B2CB71D41401361437D845A4100DE02C933B71D418C4AEAA87D845A41404ED1513EB71D4111363C357E845A41', 9.589, 47, 48),
        (29, '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', 154.823, 49, 50),
        (30, '0102000020C46E000002000000F0E236DAB9BB1D41B6F3FD246C845A41B09DEFA7CDBB1D411D5A64CB68845A41', 14.286, 51, 52),
        (31, '0102000020C46E000002000000D0A370BDEBBB1D413D0AD74B6D845A41F0E236DAB9BB1D41B6F3FD246C845A41', 13.295, 53, 51),
        (85, '0102000020C46E0000020000006032553015BF1D4196438B34F9835A416029CB1003BF1D41C9E53F64F9835A41', 4.588, 60, 66),
        (32, '0102000020C46E000006000000D03B4E51D1B91D413E7958981D845A41B09DEFA7BBB91D4173D712061D845A41709CA2A3ACB91D414ED191A01C845A41C0B12EAEA5B91D416FF085711C845A41A057CA727DB91D413CBD523E1B845A418038D6455DB91D41470378731A845A41', 31.457, 54, 55),
        (33, '0102000020C46E00000900000060AA6094F1B91D419A9999791E845A41C06B0979F2B91D41E0BE0E801E845A41E0E995F2F6B91D41ED9E3CA01E845A4110022B0766BA1D41098A1FCB21845A41D0DEE0CB78BA1D41B6F3FD5422845A41400AD723C8BA1D41B98D069C24845A4110D7A3F0CFBA1D41F7E461D524845A4190DD93C7D1BA1D41D1915CE224845A41806ABC74F3BA1D4175029AD025845A41', 70.841, 4, 34),
        (80, '0102000020C46E00000200000060F7E461EAB41D418104C5BF8F845A4100F01608F0B41D4189D2DEF091845A41', 8.931, 6, 56),
        (81, '0102000020C46E000002000000D078E96690B61D4162A1D69063845A4180734614AEB61D411B0DE0C163845A41', 7.431, 57, 31),
        (83, '0102000020C46E00000200000090635D5CA8BD1D41D3DEE0EF2D845A41709CA2A3B8BD1D41D1915CE22D845A41', 4.075, 58, 49),
        (34, '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', 173.297, 52, 22),
        (35, '0102000020C46E0000030000004003780B6FBF1D41AD69DE49F8835A41B003E70C64BF1D41BE309966F8835A416032553015BF1D4196438B34F9835A41', 22.758, 59, 60),
        (36, '0102000020C46E0000070000004082E287B5C11D410DE02DA041845A41D022DB39A5C11D41D712F29142845A418051495D82C11D418716D99644845A41907EFB7A73C11D415D6DC52E45845A41F0C9C3C24AC11D41910F7ACE46845A41807CD07335C11D41DC4603A847845A41E0141D092FC11D41EE7C3FCD47845A41', 41.954, 61, 62),
        (37, '0102000020C46E000004000000D0A370BD12C21D41E0BE0E502A845A416032553015C21D4196438B342B845A41602041311AC21D41B537F8062D845A41506210581BC21D41F2D24D722D845A41', 12.719, 21, 37),
        (38, '0102000020C46E00000C000000E002090A2EB31D41D656EC4746845A41D0E53FE45BB31D4173D712E647845A41F0E461E16DB31D412B18958848845A41605DDC4677B31D417593181449845A41B0E1E9D57FB31D413333339349845A41F0E236DA90B31D41F31FD28F4A845A41806ABC74C1B31D41091B9ECA4B845A41607FD97DC9B31D419EEFA7FE4B845A41A0559F6BD6B31D4158A835294C845A41A0DFBECE01B41D412AA913B84C845A4150499D4016B41D411D5A64FB4C845A413008AC1C56B41D412F6EA3CD4D845A41', 81.423, 63, 64),
        (40, '0102000020C46E000002000000D0C342ADC6B81D413C4ED1ED2B845A4100E78CE8AFB81D4139D6C5652D845A41', 8.18, 65, 1),
        (41, '0102000020C46E0000020000000066F76421BB1D411B0DE02D1F845A41806ABC74F3BA1D4175029AD025845A41', 28.921, 33, 34),
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
        (43, '0102000020C46E00000200000050EA04F4ACBB1D4138F8C2D86B845A41607FD97D97BB1D418D28ED596B845A41', 5.721, 67, 36),
        (44, '0102000020C46E00000400000070226C38A3BA1D414B5986488C845A417024973F9FBA1D412041F16F8C845A4100CCEEC998BA1D4190A0F8918C845A411083C08A8BBA1D41D656ECD78C845A41', 6.356, 68, 69),
        (45, '0102000020C46E00000200000060CC5DCB16C11D4132E6AE154C845A41E0E00BD30EC11D4195D409444C845A41', 2.12, 70, 71),
        (46, '0102000020C46E00000600000040F1630C30C11D41295C8FBA49845A41501E162A2EC11D41D5E76A474B845A41F041CF2629C11D41FCA9F1AA4B845A41807CD07327C11D41A913D0B44B845A41F0B050AB1FC11D41BEC117E24B845A4160CC5DCB16C11D4132E6AE154C845A41', 13.099, 72, 70),
        (47, '0102000020C46E0000090000004067446980B31D41AC8BDBAC42845A41D078E96676B31D410612146342845A41F004341175B31D41A60A465942845A4130FF21FD60B31D41182653C541845A418095438B4EB31D411B9E5E3D41845A41A0C64BB727B31D410A68221843845A41A011A5FD28B31D41C6DCB5BC43845A41B0C876BE2DB31D41D122DB2146845A41E002090A2EB31D41D656EC4746845A41', 38.787, 73, 63),
        (48, '0102000020C46E000002000000C05296E170B31D416C787A0D75845A4150158C0A23B31D41D6C56DD472845A41', 21.438, 10, 74),
        (49, '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', 83.956, 64, 75),
        (50, '0102000020C46E000003000000F09E3CAC2DB51D4130BB275B5B845A41B0FA5CED30B51D4190A0F8915C845A41F016481032B51D4105A392B261845A41', 25.436, 75, 41),
        (51, '0102000020C46E000002000000907EFB7A5AB71D41E9B7AFA73F845A418058A8B529B71D4186C9548D3D845A41', 14.813, 14, 29),
        (52, '0102000020C46E000002000000D03B4E51D1B91D413E7958981D845A41A0802682E5B91D4117D9CE271E845A41', 5.522, 54, 76),
        (53, '0102000020C46E00000500000010E9B7EFFAB61D411973D7427D845A41E0CEF7D3EFB61D4185EB51CC7D845A41303CBD52A4B61D4140A4DF7281845A41709CA2A368B61D412506815584845A41C0DCB5C45DB61D419F3C2CDC84845A41', 49.677, 46, 77),
        (54, '0102000020C46E0000030000001093A90209B61D4130BB27E788845A4170AC8B9B24B61D41F38E539087845A41C0DCB5C45DB61D419F3C2CDC84845A41', 26.686, 27, 77),
        (55, '0102000020C46E000002000000F0E236DAB9BB1D41B6F3FD246C845A4150EA04F4ACBB1D4138F8C2D86B845A41', 3.438, 51, 67),
        (56, '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', 186.067, 78, 59),
        (57, '0102000020C46E00000A000000A0C64BB7C5C11D418FC2F53019845A417024973FA6C11D419E5E29BF19845A4190B96BC9A4C11D411895D4C519845A41E0F97EEA23C11D41D6C56D141C845A4100CCEEC905C11D41910F7A9E1C845A41A0559F6BE4C01D41D5E76A371D845A41809ECDAACEC01D4129CB109B1D845A41304CA64AC1C01D41A913D0E41D845A41702D211F7DC01D41D34D625C1F845A4100D578E94DC01D41006F816020845A41', 98.282, 79, 19),
        (58, '0102000020C46E000011000000E0141D092FC11D41EE7C3FCD47845A417034803703C11D417E8CB9CB48845A417091ED7CE8C01D418716D96649845A4170931884BBC01D41EE7C3F1D4A845A4160A8358D76C01D41B6F3FD344B845A41F06C567D69C01D418D28ED694B845A41A0C420B049C01D41FCA9F1EA4B845A41506B9A7711C01D41B1BFECCE4C845A4190B20CB1EABF1D417FFB3A6C4D845A41307E8C79D9BF1D41DE0209B24D845A41501E162ACFBF1D413D0AD7DB4D845A4110022B0751BF1D41448B6CDB4F845A410010E9F7F7BE1D41E3A59B4451845A41A0CDAACF71BE1D41A323B96453845A41E068006F3EBE1D41BDE3143554845A41503789412DBE1D414A0C027B54845A414079586822BE1D41A857CAA654845A41', 201.898, 62, 23),
        (59, '0102000020C46E00000700000000F775E02AC21D41B5A67997ED835A41A0BB96D036C21D411361C3DFED835A4100F016083BC21D41A60A46F9ED835A41E0CEF7D33BC21D414F1E16FEED835A41101DC9253DC21D4125750246EE835A41D034EF3842C21D41A913D074F0835A419087859A43C21D41E09C110DF1835A41', 16.929, 80, 78),
        (60, '0102000020C46E000004000000A0559F6BDCB51D4167D5E76662845A4190B96BC97FB61D41F1F44A7563845A41E02D902082B61D4158A8357963845A41D078E96690B61D4162A1D69063845A41', 45.236, 81, 57),
        (61, '0102000020C46E000007000000704F1ED6B9B21D41F8C2645AAA845A4120E258D7BCB21D41A857CA76AB845A4140014D04C0B21D41265305A3AC845A41202FDD24C2B21D417FFB3A6CAD845A41305C8F42CBB21D41D712F2A1AD845A4100098A1FD0B21D419EEFA7BEAD845A41E0ACFA9CD8B21D4155C1A8F0AD845A41', 18.48, 13, 82),
        (62, '0102000020C46E00000600000000F01608F0B41D4189D2DEF091845A41005F984CF2B41D416EA301D492845A41D0F753E3F7B41D41014D840D95845A4160666666FBB41D418A1F636E96845A41502EFF2103B51D41B537F87699845A4190B0E1A904B51D413B70CE109A845A41', 32.883, 56, 26),
        (63, '0102000020C46E000004000000A0802682E5B91D4117D9CE271E845A4120166A0DE6B91D41CD3B4E251E845A414070CE88E7B91D410D71AC2F1E845A4110462535E9B91D41D93D793C1E845A41', 1.01, 76, 3),
        (64, '0102000020C46E00000400000030DD24C6AAB61D41D0D556746B845A41C0490C42AAB61D411B0DE07D6A845A41E02D9020A9B61D411748506868845A4180734614AEB61D411B0DE0C163845A41', 30.837, 16, 31),
        (65, '0102000020C46E00000A000000A0C64BB7ABB61D41C3D32B056D845A41F097DD93AEB61D41F697DDB76D845A412063EE5AB0B61D41B537F8266E845A41301136FCB2B61D4123DBF9CA6E845A41D0C56DB4C3B61D415D6DC5DE72845A41301AC01BCFB61D415C8FC24D74845A4190CB7FC8D7B61D41B6F3FD6475845A4110D7A3F0EBB61D41E10B93ED77845A41703D0A5718B71D41827346947B845A41806132551AB71D415DFE43BE7B845A41', 65.918, 15, 45),
        (66, '0102000020C46E000003000000B060549203C01D41C66D345822845A41806132550CC01D41CDCCCC1C22845A41002B871637C01D413D2CD4FA20845A41', 13.988, 50, 18),
        (67, '0102000020C46E00000300000090DB6880BEC11D41AB3E57EB40845A41E0E995F2B7C11D418CDB687C41845A414082E287B5C11D410DE02DA041845A41', 3.62, 38, 61),
        (68, '0102000020C46E000002000000E0141D092FC11D41EE7C3FCD47845A41009A089B31C11D41910F7A3E48845A41', 1.882, 62, 39),
        (69, '0102000020C46E00000900000050378941E1B11D41AED85F7A67845A412031082CDCB11D417DAEB63E67845A41807CD073BAB11D41615452B365845A4100197317B5B11D416F8104A162845A41802F4C26C9B11D41F38E539061845A4100CCEEC9D8B11D417E8CB9BB60845A4130189514DDB11D41DB8AFDD960845A4120C9E5BFDEB11D4139D6C5E560845A418095438BEAB11D418C4AEA3861845A41', 40.949, 83, 84),
        (70, '0102000020C46E000002000000A0559F6BDCB51D4167D5E76662845A41E068006FC9B51D41B537F84662845A41', 4.773, 81, 42),
        (71, '0102000020C46E00000200000040014D442EB31D41DB8AFD898D845A41A045B63343B31D4104560E0589845A41', 18.819, 44, 9),
        (72, '0102000020C46E000003000000404ED15126B41D41992A18A990845A41404547321CB41D41917EFB9E90845A41B003E70C10B41D4140A4DF9290845A41', 5.578, 5, 43),
        (73, '0102000020C46E00000500000060F7E461EAB41D418104C5BF8F845A415062105836B51D41917EFBAE8E845A41404ED15137B51D41CE1951AA8E845A4140696F70CAB51D41984C15EC8B845A411093A90209B61D4130BB27E788845A41', 77.862, 6, 27),
        (74, '0102000020C46E00000A000000D0C342ADC6B81D413C4ED1ED2B845A414082E287D1B81D4148E17A302B845A41E0D022DBE0B81D41C3D32B252A845A41C0F528DCF0B81D41903177A128845A41608FC275F2B81D4194F6067728845A418051495DF4B81D41C364AA4428845A41F041CF26FEB81D4176E09C4127845A4100EEEB000AB91D4117D9CE0726845A41C08F317749B91D41D6C56D341D845A413087169951B91D41061214131C845A41', 72.757, 65, 85),
        (75, '0102000020C46E0000020000003087169951B91D41061214131C845A418038D6455DB91D41470378731A845A41', 7.12, 85, 55),
        (76, '0102000020C46E000002000000806132551AB71D415DFE43BE7B845A41809ECDAA23B71D41F241CF827C845A41', 3.857, 45, 47),
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
        (78, '0102000020C46E00000C00000070226C38A3BA1D414B5986488C845A4120EBE2F6A5BA1D41B22E6E2F8C845A41A0CDAACFB1BA1D4119E258C38B845A41F0B9DACAB8BA1D4154E3A5838B845A41D0E76AEBEEBA1D411895D49589845A4110F9A0E7EFBA1D41AC8BDB8C89845A415096218E36BB1D41D122DBB185845A4180855A9338BB1D41E9B7AF8785845A4100BC05D244BB1D41C976BE8784845A4180832F8C69BB1D4117D9CE8781845A41507DAE766FBB1D419F3C2C0C81845A41302AA9937EBB1D4144696FE87E845A41', 78.281, 68, 86),
        (79, '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', 94.772, 74, 83),
        (82, '0102000020C46E00000900000080C954C1D2BC1D417E8CB9FB2D845A41B0825189D3BC1D41B98D06FC2D845A4110363C3DFCBC1D41333333132E845A41D0A145B637BD1D41D734EF342E845A41603BDF4F49BD1D41B1BFEC3E2E845A41A0DFBECE54BD1D41F7E461352E845A41E0D022DB5FBD1D419F3C2C2C2E845A41904AEA4466BD1D4160E5D0262E845A4190635D5CA8BD1D41D3DEE0EF2D845A41', 53.453, 35, 58),
        (84, '0102000020C46E000007000000302AA9937EBB1D4144696FE87E845A41C098BB969DBB1D41A323B9847A845A41D0B359B59EBB1D417B832F547A845A4110D044D8B4BB1D41F7E4619576845A41501E162ABCBB1D41F7065F5875845A41706FF085DCBB1D41B1BFECDE6F845A41D0A370BDEBBB1D413D0AD74B6D845A41', 75.576, 86, 53),
        (86, '0102000020C46E000002000000A0C64BB7C5C11D418FC2F53019845A41D0A145B6CDC11D41B5A679F71A845A41', 7.378, 79, 20),
        (87, '0102000020C46E00000200000000CE19D130C11D410A68221849845A4140F1630C30C11D41295C8FBA49845A41', 2.546, 40, 72);
```

EDIT: forgot the query:

```sql
WITH
start_poi AS (
    SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id) AS vid, geom
    FROM start_poi
    ORDER BY id
)
, end_poi AS(
    SELECT id, ((ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id)) + (SELECT MAX(vid) FROM start_poi))AS vid, geom
    FROM end_poi
    ORDER BY id
)
, distances AS (
    SELECT (start_pid * -1) AS start_vid, (end_pid * -1) AS end_vid, agg_cost as distance
    FROM pgr_withPointsCost(
        'SELECT id, source, target, cost FROM test_network'::TEXT,
        '(SELECT
            test_network.id AS edge_id,
            CASE ST_LineLocatePoint(test_network.geom, start_poi.geom)
                WHEN 0
                    THEN 0.000001
                WHEN 1
                    THEN 0.999999
                ELSE ST_LineLocatePoint(test_network.geom, start_poi.geom)
            END AS fraction
        FROM test_network, start_poi
        WHERE
            ST_DWithIN(start_poi.geom, test_network.geom, 0.001)
        ORDER BY start_poi.id)

        UNION ALL

        (SELECT
            test_network.id AS edge_id,
            CASE ST_LineLocatePoint(test_network.geom, end_poi.geom)
                WHEN 0
                    THEN 0.000001
                WHEN 1
                    THEN 0.999999
                ELSE ST_LineLocatePoint(test_network.geom, end_poi.geom)
            END AS fraction
        FROM test_network, end_poi
        WHERE
            ST_DWithIN(end_poi.geom, test_network.geom, 0.001)
        ORDER BY end_poi.id)'::TEXT,
--         (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(start_poi.vid * -1) FROM start_poi),
--         (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(end_poi.vid * -1) FROM end_poi),
        ARRAY[-33],
        ARRAY[-118,-119,-120],
        directed:=false)
)

SELECT
    (
        SELECT id
        FROM start_poi
        WHERE start_poi.vid = start_vid
    ) AS sensor_vid,
    ST_AsText((
        SELECT geom
        FROM start_poi
        WHERE start_poi.vid = start_vid
    )) AS start_geom,
    (
        SELECT id
        FROM end_poi
        WHERE end_poi.vid = end_vid
    ) AS test_point_vid,
    ST_AsText((
        SELECT geom
        FROM end_poi
        WHERE end_poi.vid = end_vid
    )) AS end_geom,
    distance
FROM distances;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution works, but it looks a bit overcomplicated.

In my opinion it is easier to first create a table containing your `POI` and then apply `pgr_withPointsCost()`

So we should have two tables:

- `test_network`
- `test_poi`

We already have `test_network` we can create `test_poi`:

```
CREATE TABLE test_poi AS
(   WITH points AS
    (
    SELECT  *
    FROM (
    VALUES  (1, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(486622.14439999964 6951376.4575)',28356)),
        (2, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(486785.6968050292 6951458.780481533)',28356)),
        (3, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(486787.0424740781 6951458.998532209)',28356)),
        (4, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(486853.7922216329 6951407.584744054)',28356))
        ) v (id,geom)
    ),
    SUB AS
    (
        SELECT closest_feature.id  as vid, g2.id as pid, closest_feature.geom as vgeom, g2.geom as pgeom
        FROM points g2
        CROSS JOIN LATERAL
            (
            SELECT id, st_distance(g1.geom,g2.geom) dist, geom
            FROM test_network g1
            WHERE st_dwithin(g1.geom,g2.geom,10)
            ORDER BY g1.geom <-> g2.geom
            LIMIT 1
            ) AS closest_feature
    )
    SELECT vid, pid, st_linelocatepoint(vgeom,pgeom) as fraction
    FROM sub
)
```

Where `test_poi` contains the following information `[the_edge_id, the_point_id, the_fraction]`

The above query do two things:

1. Create the dummy example's POI
2. For each POI find the closest edge feature.

Now we can simply call

```
SELECT * FROM pgr_withPointsCost(
    'SELECT id, source, target, cost, cost as reverse_cost from test_network',
    'SELECT pid, vid as edge_id, fraction from test_poi',
    -1, ARRAY[-2,-3,-4]);
```

And as expected we obtain:

| start_pid | end_pid | agg_cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| -1 | -2 | 340.612388279482 |
| -1 | -3 | 295.829710199085 |
| -1 | -4 | 295.828860204498 |

Comment: I like your answer and it does simplify things, but as I have separate start and end poi tables I will need to combine them and flag the row if it should be ```from_vids``` or not, then do something like ```(SELECT ARRAY_AGG(vid * -1) FROM test_poi WHERE from_vid = TRUE)``` and ```(SELECT ARRAY_AGG(vid * -1) FROM test_poi WHERE from_vid = FALSE)``` for the ```from_vids``` and ```to_vids``` parameters. I'll select this as the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Work this one out, I was getting a misalignment with the `start_poi` and `end_poi` tables/queries outside and inside the pgrouting function `pgr_withPointsCost` so when I was looking up to geom/distance to a `end_poi` I was getting the wrong geom and distance for a give id.

anyways here is there query that seems to be working:

```sql
WITH
start_poi AS (
    SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id) AS vid, geom
    FROM (
        SELECT
            DISTINCT ON (start_poi.id) start_poi.id,
            test_network.id AS edge_id,
            CASE ST_LineLocatePoint(test_network.geom, start_poi.geom)
                WHEN 0
                    THEN 0.000001
                WHEN 1
                    THEN 0.999999
                ELSE ST_LineLocatePoint(test_network.geom, start_poi.geom)
            END AS fraction,
            start_poi.geom AS geom
        FROM test_network, start_poi
        WHERE
            ST_DWithIN(start_poi.geom, test_network.geom, 0.001)
        ORDER BY start_poi.id
    ) AS tbl_start_poi
    ORDER BY id
)
, end_poi AS(
    SELECT id, ((ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id)) + (SELECT MAX(vid) FROM start_poi))AS vid, geom
    FROM (
        SELECT
            DISTINCT ON (end_poi.id) end_poi.id,
            test_network.id AS edge_id,
            CASE ST_LineLocatePoint(test_network.geom, end_poi.geom)
                WHEN 0
                    THEN 0.000001
                WHEN 1
                    THEN 0.999999
                ELSE ST_LineLocatePoint(test_network.geom, end_poi.geom)
            END AS fraction,
            end_poi.geom AS geom
        FROM test_network, end_poi
        WHERE
            ST_DWithIN(end_poi.geom, test_network.geom, 0.001)
        ORDER BY end_poi.id
    ) AS tbl_end_poi
    ORDER BY id
)
, distances AS (
    SELECT (start_pid * -1) AS start_poi_vid, (end_pid * -1) AS end_poi_vid, agg_cost as distance
    FROM pgr_withPointsCost(
        'SELECT id, source, target, cost FROM test_network'::TEXT,
        '(SELECT edge_id, fraction
        FROM (
            SELECT
                DISTINCT ON (start_poi.id) start_poi.id,
                test_network.id AS edge_id,
                CASE ST_LineLocatePoint(test_network.geom, start_poi.geom)
                    WHEN 0
                        THEN 0.000001
                    WHEN 1
                        THEN 0.999999
                    ELSE ST_LineLocatePoint(test_network.geom, start_poi.geom)
                END AS fraction
            FROM test_network, start_poi
            WHERE
                ST_DWithIN(start_poi.geom, test_network.geom, 0.001)
            ORDER BY start_poi.id
        ) AS tbl_start_poi)

        UNION ALL

        (SELECT edge_id, fraction
        FROM (
            SELECT
                DISTINCT ON (end_poi.id) end_poi.id,
                test_network.id AS edge_id,
                CASE ST_LineLocatePoint(test_network.geom, end_poi.geom)
                    WHEN 0
                        THEN 0.000001
                    WHEN 1
                        THEN 0.999999
                    ELSE ST_LineLocatePoint(test_network.geom, end_poi.geom)
                END AS fraction
            FROM test_network, end_poi
            WHERE
                ST_DWithIN(end_poi.geom, test_network.geom, 0.001)
            ORDER BY end_poi.id
        ) AS tbl_end_poi)'::TEXT,
--         (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(start_poi.vid * -1) FROM start_poi),
--         (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(end_poi.vid * -1) FROM end_poi),
        ARRAY[-33],
        ARRAY[-118,-119,-120],
        directed:=false)
)

SELECT
    (
        SELECT id
        FROM start_poi
        WHERE start_poi.vid = start_poi_vid
    ) AS start_poi_vid,
    ST_AsText((
        SELECT geom
        FROM start_poi
        WHERE start_poi.vid = start_poi_vid
    )) AS geom,
    (
        SELECT id
        FROM end_poi
        WHERE end_poi.vid = end_poi_vid
    ) AS end_poi_vid,
    ST_AsText((
        SELECT geom
        FROM end_poi
        WHERE end_poi.vid = end_poi_vid
    )) AS end_poi_geom,
    distance
FROM distances;
```

and I get results like:

| "start_poi_vid" | "geom" | "end_poi_vid" | "end_poi_geom" | "distance" |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 33 | "POINT(486622.14439999964 6951376.4575)" | 31 | "POINT(486853.7922216329 6951407.584744054)" | 340.6123882794816 |
| 33 | "POINT(486622.14439999964 6951376.4575)" | 30 | "POINT(486787.0424740781 6951458.998532209)" | 295.8297101990848 |
| 33 | "POINT(486622.14439999964 6951376.4575)" | 29 | "POINT(486785.6968050292 6951458.780481533)" | 295.82886020449797 |